# JavaScript spread operator: deep attribute is changing after cloning the object

Tags: javascript

I am getting output is 5 but I was assuming 3. what is the logic behind and how can I make output 3.

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: {
    p: 3
  }
}
const obj1 = { ...obj}
obj.c.p = 5

console.log(obj1.c.p)
```

Comment: Start off by evaluating why you thought the answer should be 3. (hint: you copied a _reference_ to `c` not the value of it)

Comment: `obj.c.p` is a reference, not an actual value. When you spread `obj` onto `obj1` the reference to `obj.c.p` is maintained, not the value, so when you do `obj.c.p = 5`, that value is updated, and `obj1` contains a reference to that value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above only clones the first level, so changing `obj`'s deep attribute will change the reference in `obj1`

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: { p: 3 }
};

const obj1 = { ...obj, c: {...obj.c} };
obj.c.p = 5;

console.log(obj1.c.p);
```

Answer (score 1):

`obj` spreaded to `obj1` but object in `c` property stays same, e.g. `c` is a same object.
Can deeply clone object like this

```
const obj1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```